# Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, matrix

Consider the following N × N matrices **A**
and **B** that contain only positive integers:

- **B** is created from **A** by summing the odd numbers that
  neighbour each element, at position `[i,j]` in **A**.
- Each computed sum is then stored in the corresponding position `[i,j]` in **B**.

For example:

- At position `[3, 2]` there are `4` odd numbers `[3, 1, 5, 3]` that
  neighbour `A[3,2]`.
- The sum of these neighbouring odd numbers is `12`,
  which is stored in `B[3,2]`

This code works by brute force, taking each of the 9 regions separately, (Namely: Top, bottom, left, right, 4 corners and inner).

Is there a better way to go about this?

```
from numpy import array,zeros,shape

def sum_neighbours(A):
    A = array(A,int)
    r,c = shape(A)
    B = zeros(shape(A),int)

    for i in range(r):
        for j in range(c):
            N_list_i = [0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0] #[l,tl,t,tr,r,br,b,bl]
            N_list_j = [-1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1]          

            # innerSquares
            if 1 <= i <= (r-2) and 1 <= j <= (r-2):
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)-1):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #TopLeft            
            elif i==0 and j==0:
                N_list_i = N_list_i[4:(4+3)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[4:(4+3)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #BottomLeft            
            elif j==0 and i==(r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[2:(2+3)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[2:(2+3)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #TopRight            
            elif i==0 and j == (r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[6:(6+3)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[6:(6+3)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #BottomRight            
            elif i == (r-1) and j == (r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[0:(0+3)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[0:(0+3)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #TopBorder            
            elif i==0 and j < (r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[4:(4+5)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[4:(4+5)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #LeftBorder            
            elif j==0 and i < (r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[2:(2+5)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[2:(2+5)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #BottomBorder            
            elif i==(r-1) and j < (r-1):
                N_list_i = N_list_i[0:(0+5)]
                N_list_j = N_list_j[0:(0+5)]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]

            #RightBorder            
            elif j==(r-1) and i < (r-1):
                N_list_i = [1,1,0,-1,-1]
                N_list_j = [0,-1,-1,-1,0]
                for k in range(len(N_list_j)):
                    if A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]] %2 != 0:
                        B[i][j] += A[i+N_list_i[k]][j+N_list_j[k]]
    return B

A = array([[3,2,8,1,1],
           [1,2,4,1,1],
           [7,3,4,1,8],
           [1,8,0,6,4],
           [5,6,5,3,8]])
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted speed of reduction of lines. I believe I have done both with more of a focus on elegance rather than performance. Nevertheless, I have also included a note on how to increase performance. Let me know if my solution helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of refactoring, you almost certainly want to avoid "brute force" in the sense of having to explicitly type out all your cases :) @alexmcf addresses this above.

In conceptual terms, your approach follows the problem statement directly: check all neighbors for each number in the matrix and sum all odd numbers. This means that you are always doing the checking and summing, **even if there are no odd numbers in the matrix.**

As an alternative: we can first run through the matrix and identify odd numbers. Then, starting from a null matrix, we simply add the odd numbers to all valid neighbors. This saves work in proportion to the sparcity of odd numbers in the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

def find_offsets(row, col, size):
    """Return all valid pairs of offsets as [(row_offset, col_offset)...]."""
    offsets = ((-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1),
               (0, -1), (0, 1),
               (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1))

    return [(r_off, c_off) for r_off, c_off in offsets
            if row + r_off >= 0 and row + r_off < size
            if col + c_off >= 0 and col + c_off < size]

def find_odds(matrix, size):
    """Return all odd values in matrix as [(row_ind, col_ind, value)...]."""
    return [(row, col, matrix[row][col])
            for row in xrange(size)
            for col in xrange(size)
            if matrix[row][col] % 2 != 0]

def gen_matrix(source, size):
    """Filter source 2x2 matrix for odds and add each to valid neighbors."""

    out = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=int)

    # filter for location and value of all odd numbers
    odds = find_odds(source, size)
    for row, col, value in odds:
        # add odd number to all valid neighbors (by finding valid offsets)
        offsets = find_offsets(row, col, size)
        for r_off, c_off in offsets:
            out[row + r_off][col + c_off] += value

    return out

def sum_neighbors():
    """Sum neighbors as described in problem."""
    N = 5
    A = [[3,2,8,1,1],
         [1,2,4,1,1],
         [7,3,4,1,8],
         [1,8,0,6,4],
         [5,6,5,3,8]]
    return gen_matrix(A, N)
```

The above runs about twice as fast as your code (for an apples-to-apples comparison, I tweaked the above when executing in iPython so that the same matrix A is provided as a parameter in both cases):

```
In [19]: %timeit original.sum_neighbours(A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 195 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit new.sum_neighbors(A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 84 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Working Code

```
import numpy as np

def sum_neighbours_NEW(A):
    A = np.array(A,int)
    r,c = np.shape(A)
    B = np.zeros(A.shape, int)

    def b(x,y, size=A.shape):
        xlim,ylim = size # get limits of axes

        # generate a list of all i,j bordering x,y
        # this will cause the most slowdown... for faster code, you minimise   
        # the number of tims idx gets called by making it a parameter of b()
        # adding x and y and doing a np.where() to ensure it doesn't 
        # index out of the array range
        idx = [[x+i,y+j] for i in range(-1,2) for j in range(-1,2) \
               if (i,j) != (0,0) and (x+i>=0 and y+j>=0) and (x+i<xlim and y+j<ylim)]
        idx = np.asarray(idx) # convert to numpy array
        return idx[:,0], idx[:,1] # split into x,y for indexing

    # iterate across all elements of A
    for i in xrange(r):
        for j in xrange(c):
            els = A[b(i,j)]
            sum_A = els[np.where(els % 2)].sum() # only sum odd elements
            B[i,j] = sum_A
    return B
```

#### Test

```
A = array([[3,2,8,1,1],
           [1,2,4,1,1],
           [7,3,4,1,8],
           [1,8,0,6,4],
           [5,6,5,3,8]])

# check new function vs. old function
(sum_neighbours(A) == sum_neighbours_NEW(A)).all()
True
```

#### Explanation

Try this loop for scanning across the 'surrounding elements', it returns a tuple of `x,y` elements split into individual `x` and `y` arrays as specified by [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
def b(x,y, size=A.shape):
    xlim,ylim = size # get limits of axes

    # generate a list of all i,j bordering x,y
    idx = [[x+i,y+j] for i in range(-1,2) for j in range(-1,2) \
           if (i,j) != (0,0) and (x+i>=0 and y+j>=0) and (x+i<xlim and y+j<ylim)]
    idx = np.asarray(idx) # convert to numpy array
    return idx[:,0], idx[:,1] # split into x,y for indexing

idx = b(3,2) 
# check correct by matching indexes e.g. 
# (idx[0][0],idx[1][0]) => (2,1) , (idx[0][1],idx[1][1]) => (2,2) etc.
print idx 
(array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Then you can access elements in **A** by:

```
els = A[idx]
print els
array([3, 4, 1, 8, 6, 6, 5, 3])
```

You can then sum all elements that are odd by:

```
print els[np.where(els % 2)].sum()
12
```

use this to obtain the sum across every element in **A**.

Answer (score 0):

The top portion of this should help out in getting just the odd elements.

```
import numpy as np
# generate an array of random integers
A = np.random.random_integers(1,10, [20,10])
# get only the odd values back from the array
A_odds = A*(A%2!=0)
# pad the array with zeros to make summing easier
A_odds_padded = np.pad(array=A_odds, pad_width=1, mode='constant')
# iterate elements and sum
B = np.zeros(np.shape(A))
for i in range(shape(B)[0]):
    for j in range(shape(B)[1]):
        #etc
```

Answer (score -2):

I have this:

```python
def find_odd_sum(arr):
    # Pad the original array
    arr_pad = np.pad(arr, 1, 'constant', constant_values=0)

    shape = np.shape(arr)
    arr_b = np.zeros((shape[0] + 2, shape[1] + 2))

    for ii in range(0, shape[0]):  #rows
        for jj in range(0, shape[1]):  #cols
            point = np.array([ii+1, jj+1])
            # Points to check
            kernel = [np.array([-1, 0]),
                      np.array([0, 1]), 
                      np.array([1, 0]), 
                      np.array([0, -1]),
                      np.array([-1, -1]),
                      np.array([1, 1]),
                      np.array([-1, 1]),
                      np.array([1, -1])]
            points = [k+point for k in kernel]
            s = [arr_pad[points[i][0], points[i][1]] for i in range(len(points))]
            s1 =sum([i for i in s if i % 2 != 0])
            arr_b[point[0], point[1]] = s1

    return arr_b[1:-1, 1:-1]



>>>
[[  1.   4.   2.   3.   3.]
 [ 13.  14.   6.   4.   4.]
 [  5.   9.   5.   2.   3.]
 [ 15.  21.  12.   9.   4.]
 [  1.  11.   3.   5.   3.]]
```

Comment: This gives an incorrect answer: If you do `arr = A` then `(arr_b[1:-1, 1:-1] == sum_neighbours(A)).any()` gives `False`

Comment: Indeed, this does not satisfy the basic example for summing odd neighbors at A[3, 2] that the OP provides.